# PHP - T_FUNCTION ERROR

Tags: php, authentication

Okay, so when I try to make a new MODULE in php, I add the .tpl .php files to the specific folders, and when i test it out the web browser just shows this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/vol11_7/epizy.com/epiz_20726987/htdocs/VA/core/modules/LoginAusmex/LoginAusmex.php on line 6
```

And the .php files code is:

```
<?php class LoginAusmex extends CodonModule
{
public function index()
{
$this->render('LoginAusmex.tpl');
}
```

If you need more details about everything just post a comment! Thanks in advance

And here is the website: http://ausmex-airline.epizy.com/VA/index.php/loginausmex

Comment: You're missing a `}`

Comment: Oh, NEVERMIND, I got it, it supposed to be: }} at the end, and thanks for your reply, I appreaciate it!